# Column configuration save

Tags: pimcore

With version 4.3.1 we are not able anymore to save column configuration in object list view. Usually we had to make our configuration, save the folder and this config was saved, now if you reload the changes are not effective anymore.
Do someone have an idea how to fix that?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Column configuration is now saved separately. After changing the column configuration a new button appears next to the "Column configuration". Click on that one to save the config - see the image

[image]